# How to Duplicate custom data?

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to duplicate my custom field data and qty while creating the new product by "duplicate & save" feature in Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite save action of the product controller

To rewrite add below code in di.xml of you module. If you dont have di.xml already in your module , create di.xml file inside etc folder. full path will be
app/code///etc/di.xml
 and add below code to di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save" type="<namepsace>\<module>\Controller\Rewrite\Product\Save.php" /> 
</config>
```

Now create Save.php on this path
\\Controller\Rewrite\Product\Save.php

add below code in Save.php

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace <namespace>\<module>\Controller\Controller\Rewrite\Product;

/**
 * Class Save
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Save extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save
{

    /**
     * Save product action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $storeId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        $store = $this->getStoreManager()->getStore($storeId);
        $this->getStoreManager()->setCurrentStore($store->getCode());
        $redirectBack = $this->getRequest()->getParam('back', false);
        $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $productAttributeSetId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('set');
        $productTypeId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('type');
        if ($data) {
            try {
                $product = $this->initializationHelper->initialize(
                    $this->productBuilder->build($this->getRequest())
                );
                $this->productTypeManager->processProduct($product);

                if (isset($data['product'][$product->getIdFieldName()])) {
                    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Unable to save product'));
                }

                $originalSku = $product->getSku();
                $product->save();
                $this->handleImageRemoveError($data, $product->getId());
                $this->getCategoryLinkManagement()->assignProductToCategories(
                    $product->getSku(),
                    $product->getCategoryIds()
                );
                $productId = $product->getEntityId();
                $productAttributeSetId = $product->getAttributeSetId();
                $productTypeId = $product->getTypeId();

                $this->copyToStores($data, $productId);

                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved the product.'));
                $this->getDataPersistor()->clear('catalog_product');
                if ($product->getSku() != $originalSku) {
                    $this->messageManager->addNotice(
                        __(
                            'SKU for product %1 has been changed to %2.',
                            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($product->getName()),
                            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($product->getSku())
                        )
                    );
                }
                $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                    'controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after',
                    ['controller' => $this, 'product' => $product]
                );

                if ($redirectBack === 'duplicate') {

                    $newProduct = $this->productCopier->copy($product);
                    /* 
                     * here you set custom product attributes to the 
                     * duplicated product
                     */
                     $newProduct->setCustomAttribute1($product->getCustomAttribute1());
                     /* 
                     * similarly you may add other attributes
                     */
                            $newProduct->save();
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You duplicated the product.'));
                }
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->getDataPersistor()->set('catalog_product', $data);
                $redirectBack = $productId ? true : 'new';
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->getDataPersistor()->set('catalog_product', $data);
                $redirectBack = $productId ? true : 'new';
            }
        } else {
            $resultRedirect->setPath('catalog/*/', ['store' => $storeId]);
            $this->messageManager->addError('No data to save');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        if ($redirectBack === 'new') {
            $resultRedirect->setPath(
                'catalog/*/new',
                ['set' => $productAttributeSetId, 'type' => $productTypeId]
            );
        } elseif ($redirectBack === 'duplicate' && isset($newProduct)) {
            $resultRedirect->setPath(
                'catalog/*/edit',
                ['id' => $newProduct->getEntityId(), 'back' => null, '_current' => true]
            );
        } elseif ($redirectBack) {
            $resultRedirect->setPath(
                'catalog/*/edit',
                ['id' => $productId, '_current' => true, 'set' => $productAttributeSetId]
            );
        } else {
            $resultRedirect->setPath('catalog/*/', ['store' => $storeId]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```